# convert elements of a dataframe to binary data

Tags: r

I have a dataframe.

```
zz <- "col1 col2 col3 
1          A         B          C
2          A         B          C
3          A         B          A
4          A         C          A
5          B         B          A
6          B         B          A"

Data <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)
```

Each column has only two values. I would like to convert to 0 the most frequent value and to 1 the least frequent value. I would like to apply this to all columns like this:

```
zz <- "col1 col2 col3 
1          1         1          0
2          1         1          0
3          1         1          1
4          1         0          1
5          0         1          1
6          0         1          1"
```

I tried this:

```
for (i in 1:3){
  Data[[i]][[names(sort(summary(as.factor(Data[[i]])),decreasing=TRUE)[1])]] <- 0
  Data[[i]][[names(sort(summary(as.factor(Data[[i]])),decreasing=TRUE)[2])]] <- 1
}
```

but get:

> Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  : 
>     replacement has 12 rows, data has 11 De plus : Warning message:
>   In `[[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, names(sort(summary(as.factor(df.matrix_binary[[i]])),  :
>     invalid factor level, NA generated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
Data[] <- lapply(Data, function(x) as.numeric(x == names(sort(table(x)))[2]))

Data
  col1 col2 col3
1    1    1    0
2    1    1    0
3    1    1    1
4    1    0    1
5    0    1    1
6    0    1    1
```

Note that based on the data you posted, I assumed you only have 2 values in each column so this doesn't do any error handling if you have more than 2 values. However, if your columns have more than two values, this can be easily modified.

Comment: Kindly change to `sort(table(x))[-1]`

Comment: @Wen, I'm concerned that will produce unexpected results if the OP has >2 values in a column. I.e. if there are 3 values then the `[-1]` will select two and the the `==` will recycle those two values in the comparison. Try `Data[,3] == names(sort(table(Data[,3])))`. Probably best to throw an error

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
Data %>%
   mutate_all(funs(match(., fct_count(., sort = TRUE)$f[1], nomatch = 0)))
#     col1 col2 col3
#1    1    1    0
#2    1    1    0
#3    1    1    1
#4    1    0    1
#5    0    1    1
#6    0    1    1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sapply(Data, function(x) as.numeric(x == levels(x)[order(-tabulate(x))][1]))
#     col1 col2 col3
#[1,]    1    1    0
#[2,]    1    1    0
#[3,]    1    1    1
#[4,]    1    0    1
#[5,]    0    1    1
#[6,]    0    1    1
```